# How to include negative value in NMDS?

Tags: r, vegan

Recently I am doing a NMDS to make group base analysis, in that data I have negative values, after performing `metaMDS` function the results showing

```
'comm' has negative data: 'autotransform', 'noshare' and 'wascores' set to FALSE
Error in pmatch(method, "euclidian") : object 'bray' not found
```

I understand that bray-curtis doesn't include negative values, but i have in my data,

what should I do to perform NMDS for negative value or which distance i should use for accepting negative value?

the code i used

```
library(vegan)
nmds_results <- metaMDS(comm = orders[,3:8],distance = bray,       
                       try = 100)
```

Comment: vegan accepts negative values for Bray-Curtis dissimilarity. You're getting an error because `bray` is not quoted. Run it with `distance = "bray"`. However, Bray-Curtis is based on counts, which cannot be negative, so it's probably not the right measure to use. To get recommendations on an appropriate distance measure you need to provide more details: What do your data look like, and what specific questions are you trying to answer with them?

Comment: vegan "accepts" negative data with Bray-Curtis dissimilarity, but issues a warning that those dissimilarities probably are meaningless.  Most dissimilarities in vegan::vegdist were designed for non-negative data (abundances, occurrences, their non-negative transformations) although some also work with general numeric data. However, we should know more about the data to give any hint. As a starter: how did you end up having negative values for something like "orders"?